# java calendar how do i return null?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jframe

```
public void loadstuff(){
    String query = "select eventname , eventtext from tblEvent where datecreate = ?";

    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = db.conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, sdf.format(calendar.getDate()));
        db.rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (db.rs.next()){
            lblEventname.setText(db.rs.getString("eventname"));
            lbleventonclick.setText(db.rs.getString("eventtext"));
        }




    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]

so i am able to successfully retrieve the eventname and eventtext, by clicking on the jcalendar date and press "getevent" button.

but how do i code it such that if i click on a date with no event, it shows "no event available" on the label. instead of showing nothing after i click the button.

what kind of if else do i put in it

Comment: What do you expect/want to happen if there is more than one event? Right now, last one wins, whichever the last one is given that you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause. If your answer is that there can be only one, then change that `while` loop into an `if-else` statement.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Why do you store the `PreparedStatement` in a local variable, but the `ResultSet` in a field of the `db` object? The `ResultSet` should also be stored in a local variable. You should also remember to close both the `ResultSet` and the `PreparedStatement`, preferable using a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `next()` *once* to test for the existence of a row:

```
db.rs = pst.executeQuery();
if (db.rs.next()) {
    lblEventname.setText(db.rs.getString("eventname"));
    lbleventonclick.setText(db.rs.getString("eventtext"));
} else {
    // no rows were returned
    lblEventname.setText("No events");
}
```

Of course this only outputs 1 row max, but that's the only thing that makes sense anyway.